# Django filter by looping through each day of a date range

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model called `Orders` which is for an e-commerce web-app and I'd like to know how many orders was made from each day in the past year. so I filtered the Orders as follows:

```
    product_orders = Order.objects.filter(
        ordered=True, variant__product=self, date__range=[(timezone.now() - timedelta(weeks=52)), timezone.now()])
```

I'd like to loop through each day from this time range and get the number of orders from each day, the result should look something like this:

```
[
    {
        date: "2021-06-21",
        quantity: 6
    },
    {
        date: "2021-06-22",
        quantity: 0
    }
]
```

the date field on the Order model is called createdAt which has default=timezone.now so I want to some what aggregate or annotate the orders created on each day on the past year

**Orders model**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="orders")
    address = models.ForeignKey(
        Address, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    variant = models.ForeignKey(
        "products.Variant", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="orders")
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    store = models.ForeignKey(
        "stores.Store", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="orders", null=True, blank=True)
    # Cart
    in_cart = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # Order
    order_group = models.ForeignKey(
        "OrderGroup", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="orders", null=True, blank=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    cancelled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    cancelled_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    # Return
    order_return_deadline = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    returning = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    returning_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    returned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    returned_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    failed_return = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # Shipping
    shipped = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    shipped_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    merchant_error = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    merchant_error_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    # Delivery
    delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delivered_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    failed_delivery = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    failed_delivery_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.last_name}'s Order"
```

where the quantity is `Order.objects.filter(...).count()`

Comment: It is easy to do this per day, but the days with no quantities will not be in the queryset, you will need to do post-processing on the result to fill in these items.

Comment: Can you share relevant parts of your `Order` model?

Comment: the date field on the Order model is called `createdAt` which has `default=timezone.now` so I want to some what aggregate or annotate the orders created on each day on the past year @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: please [edit] the question. Does an order has a quantity (and thus sum up the quantity) or count the number of *orders* (these two are *not* the same)

Comment: count the number of orders

Comment: that's why i added `Order.objects.filter(...).count()`

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate your `Order` with the number of `Order`s with:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

now_ = now()

product_orders = Order.objects.filter(
    ordered=True,
    variant__product=self,
    created_at__range=(now_-timedelta(weeks=52)), now_())
).values(
    date=TruncDate('created_at__date')
).annotate(
    quantity=Count('pk')
).order_by('date')
```

This will return a `QuerySet` with dictionaries as items, these thus look like:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'date': date(2021, 6, 21), 'quantity': 6 },
    {'date': date(2021, 6, 23), 'quantity': 3 }
]>
```

If a certain date has no orders, then that date will not be included in the output. We thus will have to post-process the data.

We can do that by first working with a dictionary that maps dates to quantities, we can do that with:

```
temp = { po['date'].date(): po['quantity'] for po in product_orders }
```

and then set a default to `0` for the `date`s and add these to the `result` list:

```
result = [
    {'date': (now_-timedelta(days=dy)).date(), 'quantity': temp.setdefault((now_-timedelta(days=dy)).date(), 0)}
    for dy in range(52*7+1)
]
```

then `result` contains a list of dictionaries with the `date` and the `quantity`.

Comment: Thank you so much let me try this

Comment: Every entry is giving me quantity zero, I'm guessing is from the `Count("pk")` why are you using `pk`

Comment: @Damiisdandy: do you have orders of the last 52 weeks for that product and that are ordered?

Comment: @Damiisdandy: what if you look at `list(prduct_orders)`, can yo see this two orders?

Comment: yes i can see the two orders after doing that with their quantity but zero in quantity in result

Comment: i've found a solution

Comment: @Damiisdandy: and it is a `date` object, not a `datetime` object for the `date` field?

Comment: @Damiisdandy: can you `print(product_orders.query)`?

Comment: i changed `created_at` to `ordered_date`, this is what I got `SELECT "accounts_order"."ordered_date" AS "date", COUNT("accounts_order"."id") AS "quantity" FROM "accounts_order" INNER JOIN "products_variant" ON ("accounts_order"."variant_id" = "products_variant"."id") WHERE ("accounts_order"."ordered" AND "accounts_order"."ordered_date" BETWEEN 2020-09-13 22:37:21.574840 AND 2021-09-12 22:37:21.574856 AND "products_variant"."product_id" = 57) GROUP BY "accounts_order"."ordered_date" ORDER BY "date" ASC`

Comment: @Damiisdandy: you should use `F('ordered_date__date')` (so with a `__date` lookup).

Comment: ` product_orders = Order.objects.filter(ordered=True,variant__product=self, ordered_date__range=((now_()-timedelta(weeks=52)), now_()) ).values( date=F('ordered_date__date')).annotate(quantity=Count('pk')).order_by('date')`

Comment: the problem is that its separating orders on the same day
`<QuerySet [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 17, 16, 23, 53, 715000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'quantity': 1}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 17, 18, 3, 49, 183000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'quantity': 1}]>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237038/discussion-between-damiisdandy-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 0):

I simply just looped through the dates of the past year, then filter and count

```
product_orders = Order.objects.filter(
            ordered=True,
            variant__product=self,
            ordered_date__range=(timezone.now()-timedelta(weeks=52), timezone.now()))

        result = []
        # looping through to get each day from now to a year ago
        for day in range(52*7+2):
            date = (timezone.now()-timedelta(days=day)).date().isoformat()
            result.append({
                "day": date,
                "quantity": product_orders.filter(ordered_date__date=date).count()
            })
```

this solution gave me accurate results, if you have a more effective way I'm open to it. BTW I changed `created_at` to `ordered_date`

**MORE EFFICIENT SOLUTION**

```
        now_ = timezone.now
        product_orders = Order.objects.filter(
            ordered=True,
            variant__product=self,
            ordered_date__range=((now_()-timedelta(weeks=52)), now_())
        ).annotate(date=functions.TruncDay("ordered_date")).values("date").annotate(quantity=Count("id")).values("date", "quantity").order_by('date')
        temp = {po['date'].date(): po['quantity'] for po in product_orders}
        result = [
            {'date': (now_()-timedelta(days=dy)).date(),
             'quantity': temp.setdefault((now_()-timedelta(days=dy)).date(), 0)}
            for dy in range(52*7+1)
        ]
```

Comment: but this will make 365 queries, and thus is inefficient.

Comment: could you help me in making it efficient

Comment: that's exactly why we need `.annotate(...)` to make *one* query, not 300+.